# Spring cannot find bean in basic Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and put an application together with a DemoApplication (main class) and a class called CodeChallenge. Both of these classes are in the same folder. I autowired the CodeChallenge class into the main class and am using      `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` so the class will trigger when it is compiled. However, whenever I compile the app I get the following error:

```
Field codechallenge in com.example.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of 
type 'com.example.demo.CodeChallenge' that could not be found.
```

How can I successfully configure this application so I can avoid this error and run the CodeChallenge class and testMethod when compiling the program?

The DemoApplication class is:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

@SpringBootApplication    
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private CodeChallenge codechallenge;  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

      @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
      public void callTestMethod() {
          codechallenge.testMethod();   
      }

}
```

And the CodeChallenge class is:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class CodeChallenge {
    public void testMethod() {          
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a `@Service` or `@Component` annotation on `public class CodeChallenge` to let Spring know thats a bean.

```
@Service
public class CodeChallenge {
    public void testMethod() { 
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```